# How to reload a method when changing to another page in ASP.NET gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, paging

I've got a GridView and now I wan't to reload a method whenever the next page is in use.
This is my GridView, as you can see there's a method for onPageIndexChanging.
Is this the way I have to do it?

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdvProductChurn" runat="server" CellPadding="4" HeaderStyle-BorderStyle="None" 
    BorderColor="#666666" BorderStyle="Solid" AllowPaging="True" AutoGenerateColumns="false" PageSize="30" DataSourceID="DataSource_ProductChurn" 
    AllowSorting="True" ForeColor="#666666" CellSpacing="1" DataFormatString="{0:###,###,###,###,###}" 
    CaptionAlign="Left"  Width="960px" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" HorizontalAlign="Center" CssClass="GridView2"
    Height="119px" OnRowCreated="grdvProductChurn_RowCreated" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" >
```

And then this is the codebehind:

```
    protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging()
{
    grdvProductChurn_DataBound();

}
```

It gets a compiler error CS0123.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the expected arguments for the event handler. Also, you should use `DataBind()` to force the grid to rebuild.

```
protected void gridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e) {
    grdvProductChurn.DataBind();
}
```